# error when comparing dates in sidekiq-cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, sidekiq

When run sidekiq, in log receive this error:

```
ERROR: CRON JOB: comparison of Time with EtOrbi::EoTime failed
ERROR: CRON JOB: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@script-admin/gems/sidekiq-cron-0.3.1/lib/sidekiq/cron/job.rb:434:in `<'
```

error in this place

```
def not_enqueued_after?(time)
  @last_enqueue_time.nil? || @last_enqueue_time < last_time(time)
end
```

sidekiq running, but logs out this error. and cron workers not started.

maybe it's because I compare the object `EtOrbi::EoTime` with ruby's standard `DateTime` object

Tell me how to fix? thanks

Comment: Use EtOrbi::EoTime#to_time

Comment: thanks, fill in the answer if you want, I will put +

Comment: Added, thank you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`EtOrbi::EoTime#to_time`](https://github.com/floraison/et-orbi/blob/master/lib/et-orbi.rb#L300) before comparison.